# how to average a tensor axis with specified mask in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

For example:

I have a input `tensor(input)`, shaped `(?,10)` `dtype=float32`, the first dimension means `batch_size`.

And a mask `tensor(mask)`, shaped `(?,10)`. `mask[sample_number]` is like `[True,True,False,...]`, means the masks

And a label tensor(avg_label), shaped `(?,)` ,means the correct mean value of masked positions for each sample

I want to train the model , but can't find a good way to get the output.

The **`tf.reduce_...`** (e.g. **`tf.reduce_mean`**) functions don't seem to support argument about masking.

I try **`tf.boolean_mask`** ,But it will flatten the output shape into only one dimension,throwing the sample_number dimension, so it cannot differentiate among the samples

I considered **`tf.where`**, like:

```
masked=tf.where(mask,input,tf.zeros(tf.shape(input)))
avg_out=tf.reduce_mean(masked,axis=1)
loss=tf.pow(avg_out-avg_label,2)
```

But the code above is certainly not working because False set to 0 will change avg. If use np.nan ,it will always get nan.  i wonder if there is a value representing absence when doing reduce operations.

How can i do this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You have an input tensor shaped (?, 10), a masked tensor shaped (?, 10) and you want to get the mean of the input, only for those values where `mask=True`. Is that right?

Comment: yes,it is the meaning.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `tf.ragged.boolean_mask` to keep the dimensionality.

```
tf.reduce_mean(tf.ragged.boolean_mask(x, mask=mask), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tf.boolean_mask`.

```
In [17]: tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
In [18]: mask = np.array([[True, False], [False, True], [True, False]])
In [19]: masked = tf.boolean_mask(tensor, mask)
In [20]: masked.eval()
Out[20]: array([1, 4, 5], dtype=int32)
In [21]: tf.reduce_mean(masked).eval()
Out[21]: 3
```

For the False masked values you can use tf.logical_not to toggle the mask.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own mean function by just counting the non-vanishing entries in your mask

Why not just

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

B, H, W, C = 5, 224, 224, 3

data = np.random.randn(B, H, W, C).astype(np.float32)
mask = np.random.randint(2, size=(B, H, W, C)).astype(np.float32)

expected = (data * mask).sum(axis=(1, 2, 3), keepdims=True)
expected = expected / mask.sum(axis=(1, 2, 3), keepdims=True)

data_op = tf.convert_to_tensor(data)
mask_op = tf.convert_to_tensor(mask)

actual_op = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(data, mask), axis=[1, 2, 3], keepdims=True) / tf.reduce_sum(mask, axis=[1, 2, 3], keepdims=True)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    actual = sess.run(actual_op)

np.testing.assert_allclose(actual, expected)
```

Comment: If this wasn't sarcasm, feel free to accept it. Otherwise please change your question accordingly, so you really get the information you need.

Comment: I might suggest using `tf.math.divide_no_nan` if using this in the context of padding.  Stuff on the ends of sequences might have all zeros in the mask along whatever dimension you're reducing.