# combine gather_nd with aggregation in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following operation I want to perform on a tensor:
[image]

I want to average values per row, but the number of values per row can be different as shown in the figure.
I tried the following code but got stuck after `gather_nd`, how should I aggregate it now the way I want?

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.constant(
    [
        [4, 4, 2, 4, 1],
        [6, 7, 6, 2, 4],
        [1, 0, 7, 6, 9],
        [5, 4, 1, 7, 4],
        [1, 2, 0, 3, 1]
    ]
)

indices = tf.constant([
    [0, 0], [0, 3],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 1], [2, 4],
    [3, 4],
    [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 4]
])

print(tf.gather_nd(data, indices))
# --> tf.Tensor([4 4 6 0 9 4 1 2 1], shape=(9,), dtype=int32)
# now how to aggregate per row?
```

P.S. - This should generalize to higher dimensions (the reason I used 2D matrices is that it is easier to convey). This means that `data` will be 3D instead of 2D and each element in `indices` will contain 3 items instead of 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved it using masks.

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.constant(
    [
        [4, 4, 2, 4, 1],
        [6, 7, 6, 2, 4],
        [1, 0, 7, 6, 9],
        [5, 4, 1, 7, 4],
        [1, 2, 0, 3, 1]
    ]
)

indices_no_batch = [
    [0, 3],
    [2],
    [1, 4],
    [4],
    [0, 1, 4]
]
batch_idxs = tf.repeat(tf.range(5), [len(row_size) for row_size in     indices_no_batch])
flat_list = [item for sublist in indices_no_batch for item in sublist]

index_to_data = tf.stack([batch_idxs, flat_list], axis=1)
candidate_mask = tf.scatter_nd(index_to_data, tf.ones(tf.shape(index_to_data)    [0]), tf.shape(data))
print(tf.reduce_mean(tf.ragged.boolean_mask(data, mask=tf.cast(candidate_mask, 'bool')), axis=1))
# --> tf.Tensor([4.         6.         4.5        4.         1.33333333], shape=(5,), dtype=float64)
```

credit to this answer - [how to average a tensor axis with specified mask in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375115/how-to-average-a-tensor-axis-with-specified-mask-in-tensorflow)